# React fetching data then passing as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a view that contains several components.

```
class ProfileView extends React.Compnent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: {}
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetchData((res) => {
      this.setState({user: res});
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeComponent user={this.state.user} />
        <AnotherComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Since this is making an async call and rendering the state as an empty object on the initial redner, it's causing what I think to be a problem?

Inside my inner component I have to write validation, which is ok but feels wrong, that is why I am asking this question, is the validation in the example below good practice or am I making a mistake.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Compnent {
  render() {
    if(typeof this.props.user !== 'undefined' && !$.isEmptyObject(this.props.user)) {
      return (
        <div>
          <SomeComponent user={this.state.user} />
          <AnotherComponent />
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

This is the best I could come up with, it works ok but there is a slight jump in my UI because initially I am just rendering a `<div>`.

How can I improve my approach, or is this the ideal way to do it?

Comment: Just change your parent component to not render `SomeComponent` when data is not ready.

Comment: Passing props to child component is the right way. The code looks good.

Comment: You can use Skeleton components. When the props is undefined, just show the skeletons and when the fetching is complete, so the data. This way it will be more user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is close to what I would do.  I think that the best solution is to initially render a component that indicates to the user that data is being fetched from the server.  Once that data comes back, you can update the state of your parent component, which will case the child component to render instead.  A potential solution might look something like this:

```
function renderChildComponent() {
    const {user} = this.state;

    if (user) {
        return <Child user={user} />;
    }

    return <Loading />;
}

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: undefined
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetchData(response => {
            this.setState({user: response});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {renderChildComponent.call(this)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Or put the `renderChildComponent()` in the Parent component and call it like `{this.renderChildComponent()}`

Comment: Yes, both are valid options, but doing so would make that function publicly accessible from the component class - one could import this component in another file, instantiate the component like so: `const parentComponent = React.createElement(Parent);`, and call that function like `parentComponent.renderChildComponent();`.  Since there is really no reason to make this function publicly accessible, one should probably err on the side of not doing so.

Comment: renderChildComponent code could be within render. The code is much more readable.

Comment: I disagree that it would be more readable inside of the `render` function, but to each their own.